# Keyboard, Mouse and Tower Power Button of PC Stopped Working

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Keyboard and mouse connected to my PC stopped working all of a sudden. Checked all connections. Everything looks fine. But keyboard and mouse don't work. Then I tried to restart the PC by tower power button as keyboard and mouse isn't functioning. It also doesn't work.

My question is:

- how to turn off or restart PC safely?
- how to resolve keyboard and mouse issue?

I have triple boot on the PC. Currently Windows XP is running and computer is locked. I can't type password nor restart is possible.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. My update to question wasn't an answer to it. I thought the question should be removed. But I don't know how to do that. So posted the update for moderators.

Comment: We don't close questions just because you have found the answer (your update to the question **was** the answer). Instead you can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be with recognising the keyboard and mouse. Earlier I had a device connected to PC via USB. I removed the device without ejecting it safely from the eject button. The computer still displayed the removed device as present there. So I think the issue was detecting the hardware.

After restart keyboard and mouse worked properly. The tower power button issue was mistakenly assumed.

This solution helped me :

> Unplug USB cables and wait for a little while for the device driver to be unloaded by Windows, and then plug the device back in.

[Mouse, touchpad, and keyboard problems in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/17417/windows-mouse-touchpad-keyboard-problems)

Source of the solution and for the issues of keyboard, mouse in Windows this support article is helpful.